# Sorting JTable after adding rows

Tags: java, database, swing, sorting, jtable

I have to sort `JTable (Object[][] data, Object[] headers)` after adding new row.

Here is the code (doesn't work)

```
public class Window extends JFrame {
    Window() {
        super();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JTable table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(null, new String[]{"col1"}));
        TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(table.getModel());
        sorter.setComparator(0, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
        });
        sorter.setSortsOnUpdates(true);
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);

        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
        model.addRow(new String[] {"A"});
        model.addRow(new String[] {"C"});
        model.addRow(new String[] {"B"});

        this.getContentPane().add(table);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Window();
    }
}
```

Output result : table (A, C, B) , expected (A, B, C)

model - DefaultTableModel
deviceTable - Jtable

Comment: For best help, please create and post a valid [mcve] -- a small program, small enough to post in your question completely as code-formatted text, one that we can compile and run without modification, and that demonstrates your problem for us.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels added MCVE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, you need to define a sort key, otherwise the table is effectively unsorted...

```
List<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<RowSorter.SortKey>();
sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(0, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
table.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

The following example (based on yours), sorts the first column.  When you tap the button, it adds the rows, which are then sorted

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.RowSorter;
import javax.swing.SortOrder;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                JTable table = new JTable();
                table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(null, new String[]{"col1"}));
                TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(table.getModel());
                sorter.setComparator(0, new Comparator<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                        return o1.compareTo(o2);
                    }
                });
                sorter.setSortsOnUpdates(true);
                List<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<RowSorter.SortKey>();
                sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(0, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
                sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
                table.setRowSorter(sorter);

                JButton btn = new JButton("...");
                btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                        model.addRow(new String[]{"A"});
                        model.addRow(new String[]{"C"});
                        model.addRow(new String[]{"B"});
                    }
                });

                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! It's really works, but only visual (when i select row and calls table.getSelectedRow() , it returns old position)

Comment: Yes, `RowSorter` does a "virtual" sort, sorting the row indices which are then mapped between the view and the model. You need to use the `JTable#convertRowIndexToModel` and `JTable#convertRowIndexToView` to translate between the model and view. All of this is covered in the [How to use tables, Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) tutorial - This means that the model is never modified

Answer (score 1):

```
model.fireTableDataChanged();
```

Don't invoke the fireXXX() methods directly.

It is the responsibility of thehe TableModel will invoke the appropriate method (which in this case would be fireTableRowsInserted).

Edit:

Get rid of the code that creates the sorter and the Comparator.

You just let the table create the sorter. But then once you do this you need to tell the sorter which column to sort:

```
table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
((DefaultRowSorter)table.getRowSorter()).toggleSortOrder(0);
```

Comment: It doesn't help

Comment: Then post your [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. So you start by testing with hard coded data to keep the `MCVE` complete since we don't need access to your custom object to prove that the model will automatically be sorted when data is added. Also, there is no need for the revalidate() and repaint(). Swing components will automatically repaint themselves when the model is changed. Finally, why are you using a custom Comparator? A String Comparator will be used by default.

Comment: how can i pass default string comparator?